# Batch conversion of .hgt files to .tif using Powershell returns filename.hgt.tif files

Tags: geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate, for-loop, hgt, powershell

I have a folder which contains DEM in .hgt. I want to convert them via GDAL. So to convert a single file, it's `gdal_translate -of 'GTiff' N16E122.hgt N16E122.tif`. To do it in Powershell, I figured it's something like a for-loop which contains the GDAL command but parameterized.

I tried this based on this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/18847285/12779978

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\me\Desktop\New folder"
foreach ($f in $files){
    $outfile = $f.FullName + ".tif"
    Get-Content $f.FullName | gdal_translate -of GTiff *.hgt $f.tif | Set-Content $outfile
}
```

The command returns 4 `FAILURE: No target dataset specified.` errors and the result is a `.hgt.tif` file for each of the input file like `N16E122.hgt.tif`. I've tried numerous combinations for the `$outfile` variable and the GDAL `dst_dataset` parameter but nothing works.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Solved. The .tif files are loading properly in QGIS.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem .
foreach ($f in $files){
$path = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\New folder\"
$infile = $f.FullName
$outfile = $path + $f.BaseName + ".tif"
Get-Content $f.FullName | gdal_translate -of GTiff $infile $outfile
}
```